# Como escrever e bloquear a textbox ao clicar no botão

Tags: c#, winforms

Queria saber como que faz para escrever na textbox um número e bloquear quando o botão for clicado

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        textBox4.Enabled = false;
 }
```

Consegui fazer bloquear, mas escrever dentro dela não consegui, alguém me explica como faz isto?

Comment: Web ou Windows Forms?

Comment: Windows Forms, desculpe não esclarecer

Comment: Sim, mais estou dizendo que quando clicar no botão ele bloqueia e que já esteja digitado. É como se tivesse um valor padrão e não pudesse editar

Comment: Isso, e também queria saber como faz para quando clicar no botão a textbox aparecer bloqueado com o valor padrão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo código e comentários só é preciso o bloqueio da digitação, em vez de utilizar [`Enabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx) que é bem restritivo e desabilita inclusive eventos utilize [`ReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byfd5ch8(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox4.Text = "Texto Padrão";
    textBox4.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Para aparecer quando der um duplo `click` que o mesmo está bloqueado para digitação, vai na caixa de eventos e utilize [`DoubleClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx):

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private void textBox4_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Bloqueado !!!");
}
```

Para iniciar o [`TextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) sem visibilidade:

`Form_Load`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox4.Visible = false;
}
```

ou ***caixa de propriedades***:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo acho que consegui perfeitamente fazer oque eu queria usando seus exemplos, só troquei o ReadOnly por Enabled = false; para ficar do jeito que eu queria, agora me explica como faz para que quando o programa fosse aberto, a textbox não aparecesse, e só aparecesse se apertar no botão? Obrigado.

Comment: Muito obrigado me ajudou muito.